# Blank Screen - Only wallpaper shows up

Tags: windows, login, wubi, desktop-background, iso

I installed Ubuntu from wubi in the ISO and chose the option run alongside windows. I installed it on a separate hard-disk. **After I login just a blank screen shows up** (shows a **wallpaper** and **moving cursor though**). I don't know what to do. Please help me soon.

Comment: Is it Ubuntu 11.10? Are you getting a Login screen?

Comment: press Alt+Ctrl+F1 doest it go to text mode then?

Comment: @Rajesh, please edit your question, and tell us what version of Ubuntu and what version of Windows are you using. Some hardware info will be nice too.

Comment: Yes it is Ubuntu 11.10...I am getting login screen fine

Comment: I use Windows 7...Pretty Old Computer: Pentium Dual Core - 2.8Ghz...1Gb DDR2 RAM...ATI Radeon XPRESS 200 Series Chipset.

Comment: I didn't try Alt+Ctrl+F1...will now.

Comment: can u try to login to "Unity 2d" from the drop down menu at login screen?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can log in.
Ok, let's try it:

1. try to bring up a terminal to you with Ctrl+Alt+T or with @Misery suggestion in comments.
2. type in terminal

   **unity --reset**
3. Get in X with Ctrl+Alt+7 (?)
4. If (3) fails, type this on terminal

   **sudo reboot 0**

   enter password and hit Enter.

I am really not sure if this gonna works because I am a Ubuntu noob too. But good luck! =D

Comment: Sometimes I get the icons and everything but the keyboard and mouse stop working...I tried reconnecting them but failed. What should I do now? I am gonna uninstall and reinstall again by completely disconnecting the windows HDD and use the other one. This works fine on my netbook but is diff. to use because of the small screen.